# Usage of [formGroup] on Angular Arrayform

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-template

i want to understand this usage.
I create a form like this

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  values: this.fb.array([this.group()])
});
```

Is a simple FormArray. I want to put it into Angular Material Table.
My html seems like this:

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="values">
      <button (click)="addValues()">Add Values</button>
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="values.controls">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="column1">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>column1</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" [formGroup]="item">
            <input type="text" formControlName="column1" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>
       </table>
    </div></form>
```

Now my question is simple. Why i must define [formGroup]="item" on each field of my form? Without this doesn't work.
What's the meaning of this ?
Thank you

Comment: An array is a collection of form groups. If you wish to display several form groups, I don't see how you can do it without using the `formGroup` attribute.

Comment: Yes, i know, but i imagine to use [formGroup] for each row , not for each field.

Comment: On each row it would be a `FormControl`, not a form group.

Comment: maybe i badly explained. My form is composed by a ROW that contains various field. So i think each row is a ForGroup and each field on this row is a FormControl

Comment: That's supposed to be the case yes. The issue is that material tables don't behave like real HTML tables, so it might get confusing.